# Ho can I keep constraints of xib when I add this into UIViewController's scroll?

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints, xib, ios-autolayout

I have a xib with constraints, and I have a viewController in my autolayout storyboard with a scrollView where I added the xib.

My xib have constraints, but when I add the xib to the autolayout storyboard the outlets change position and size, it is losing his constraints...

I use this function to create the xib :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {

        nibname=@"myViewXib";

        [self addSubview:
         [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myViewXib" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];
        [self setNeedsLayout];

    }
    return self;
}
```

And this is the function to load the xib into my storyboard in the viewDidLoad:

```
MyViewXib *myView = [[MyViewXib alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.scroll.frame.origin.x, self.scroll.frame.origin.y, self.scroll.frame.size.width, self.scroll.frame.size.height)];
[myView setFrame:CGRectMake(width*count++, 0, width, height)];
[self.scroll addSubview:myView];
[self.scroll layoutSubviews];
```

[image]

[image]

What is wrong in my code? Why are the constraints not working?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting add subview code in the viewDidLoad method you can try it by putting it in viewDidAppear method since the view controller don't have the exact frame of any view in viewDidLoad method.